# How do I use the Youtube API to check if a video viewing is restricted?

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

Video can be restricted, if it's video is set to be not available for users region, if it is private or if video owner has set limitations on where it can be displayed. I don't want to display them.

Query what I have at the moment:

```
Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.GetStandardFeed(
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2" +
    "&format=5&iv_load_policy=3&q=" + this.textBox1.Text);
```

Initially I build a list of type item, that acts as a datasource. Precondition here could also fix my problem.

```
foreach (Video entry in feed.Entries) 
    dsList.Add(new item { ID = entry.VideoId, TITLE = entry.Title });
```

How do I use the Youtube API to check if a video viewing is restricted?

### edit:

I assumed, I can use:

```
foreach (Video entry in feed.Entries) 
    if (entry.Status == null)
        dsList.Add(new item { ID = entry.VideoId, TITLE = entry.Title });
```

But there are at least 2 problems with that:

1. Youtube api can maximally return 50 items over 10 pages per query. Maximum of 500 items - that is more, then gets used in average case. But if restricted content has higher ordering precedence (example: major label music videos), then 99% or more results can get thrown away.
2. Filter works for most cases, but it does not seem to work for (EMI : [Coldplay - Every Teardrop Is A Waterfall (Official)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Kf_6BWcOOg)), that is listed under top rated videos feed. I don't want to display:

[image]

Comment: Would using regionId in the API URL help?

Comment: @Adithya Surampudi: It would not.

Answer (score 2):

The YouTube API includes an attribute called accessControl. This includes fields that tell you whether embedding and playback on mobile devices and televisions is allowed.

See this page for more:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:accessControl

Comment: I know it's an old question, but I was looking for the same thing as you, and found the solution, so I thought I'd share it.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the API documentation on [custom parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#Custom_parameters).

Specifically the *restriction* and *region* parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution

```
 Public Function IsVideoExits(VideoID As String) As Boolean
    Try
        If Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(WC.DownloadData("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/" + VideoID + "/hqdefault.jpg"))).Height > 0 Then Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

You could find if the video is exits/Allowed to view in this way in 6 code lines even without the API

That's a VB code. Think U could convert to your own